# how http.sys sends the request to the worker process?

Tags: asp.net

I heard that the http.sys will act as the forwarder of the request to the worker process... the question is
how it will send the request to worker process?
if it is through the network then how it will send the request through the network?

Answer (score 0):

You can share socket between application by calling [WSADuplicateSocket](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms741565(v=vs.85).aspx) function. You can read it in detail.

So once http.sys accepts a connection, it then calls this or equivalent of this API to transfer socket to your worker process.